# listen to azure queue message from python fro web job

Tags: python, azure, queue, azure-webjobs

i am trying to listen to azure queue from a worker role in python.
is there a way to write a function that will trigger only when a new message is coming ?
the template code with the Python Tools for Visual Studio is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
while True:
    #
    # Write your worker process here.
    #
    # You will probably want to call a blocking function such as
    #    bus_service.receive_queue_message('queue name', timeout=seconds)
    # to avoid consuming 100% CPU time while your worker has no work.
    #
    sleep(1.0)
```

i can see that for service bu there is a listen function but i could not find one for the queue api

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage#how-to-get-the-queue-length) for Azure Queue Storage in Python, the steps for your code like as below.

1. Get the queue length to judge for processing or wait for a moment
2. If the queue length is greater than 0, dequeue or just peek messages to process.

Here is the code.

```
# Step 1: Get the count of messages in a queue
metadata = queue_service.get_queue_metadata('taskqueue')
count = metadata.approximate_message_count
if count > 0:
   # Step 2: Process messages
   # Dequeue messages
   messages = queue_service.get_messages('taskqueue')
   # Or peek messages, `messages = queue_service.peek_messages('taskqueue')`
   for message in messages:
       print(message.content) # process message like print
       queue_service.delete_message('taskqueue', message.id, message.pop_receipt)

sleep(1.0)
```

Meanwhile, just recommend, the other way instead of webjob, you can consider to use Azure Function Apps with Queue Storage trigger in Python as below, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue).

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is function apps can be suitable for long running  tasks lie nlp analysis ?

Comment: @royi Not, I think. Function Apps is a serverless framework for web, I don't think it's a good idea to use it for NLP analysis like NLTK in Python.

Comment: Python is still experimentally supported in Function App. no to use in production environment.

Comment: Documentation is out of date